# Change MasterDetailPage.Master?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a MasterDetailPage, and I need to replace dynamically the Master page without destroying the Detail page.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new MasterDetailPage()
    {
        Master = new Page1(),
        Detail = new NavigationPage( new PageXXX() )
    };
}
```

Tried with the direct approach, which looks intuitive:

```
private void onTestButtonClicked( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {

            ( (MasterDetailPage)( Application.Current ).MainPage ).Master =  new Page2();

        }
```

but it throws me an error, which by some reason I can not trace back to the source :

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 13:17. StaticResource not found for key itemTemplate'
```

- how to dynamically replace the Master of MasterDetailPage ?

Comment: the `XamlParseException` is telling you there is an error in your `Page2` XAML.

Comment: @Jason You've just saved a mans life. This is actually the answer on a hours long headbanging trying to make a space for a new window on the wall. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP says the comment solved the problem. Typo on the new page.